# How to build simple SPARQL query in the right way

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am novice with SPARQL and DBpedia.

I would like to get knowledge of building simple SPARQL queries.

Could you please help me to build answer for such questions as: 
Hometown of footballer (any one), List of Artists, List of Oscar winners (any year)

Comment: I've voted to close as "too broad": **There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.**  The general answer is that there's no general answer for SPARQL and RDF;  the processes depends on the structure of the data.  In this case, the data is DBpedia, so your best best is to explore the data.  E.g., find an Oscar winner, e.g., [Brad Pitt](http://dbpedia.org/page/Brad_Pitt), browse the data to see what indicates an Oscar winner.

Comment: In this case, you'll see some dcterms:subject links that bring you to a category, and you'll find, eventually http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Academy_Award_winners.  Then you can search for members of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this question is probably too broad, but in case it's useful, it might make sense to describe how to *approach* this type of problem.  For one of the problems, here's what I did.

### List of Oscar winners (any year)

In this case, I started by visting the DBpedia entry for an Academy Award winner, [Brad Pitt](http://dbpedia.org/page/Brad_Pitt).  There you'll see the property **dcterms:subject [category:Producers_who_won_the_Best_Picture_Academy_Award](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Producers_who_won_the_Best_Picture_Academy_Award)**.
That category has property 
**skos:broader
[category:Best_Picture_Academy_Award_winners](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Best_Picture_Academy_Award_winners)** which, in turn, has
**skos:broader

[category:Academy_Award_winners](http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Academy_Award_winners)**.  So you could look for things that have a **dcterms:subject** value of some category that's connected by a path of **skos:broader** links to the **Academy_Award_winners** category.  That will actually turn up some things that aren't persons, because those categories are categories of *articles*, not classes of entities, so you'll also want to filter down to those things which are Persons.  That's *probably* going to give you a list of Academy Award winners, though it's possible that some are just in that category because they have some other relationship to the category:

```sql
select ?person where {
  ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person ;
          dcterms:subject/skos:broader* category:Academy_Award_winners .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fperson%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3APerson%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dcterms%3Asubject%2Fskos%3Abroader*%20category%3AAcademy_Award_winners%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: how to add here 2010 year for example?

Comment: You specifically said in the question, *List of Oscar winners **(any year)** *, so I don't really see why that matters.  And on top of that, I described the process that *I* used to find some data:  I browsed the data to find what I was looking for, and then wrote a query based on that.  There's no reason you can't do the same thing.  *Look* in the data for an indication of the year, and then *write* a query based on the shape of that data.  People will be very reluctant to provide help if it appears that you're not willing to make any attempts, especially on tasks that seems like homework.

Comment: Thank you! I will do it now. I have read carefully your notes.

Comment: This language is very differs from SQL, I could not solve easy filtering by year. Could you please point me about it?

Comment: Before writing any SPARQL at all, what did you find **in the data** that indicates the year?  You wouldn't write any SQL before knowing the tables and columns in a database;  you shouldn't write any SPARQL before knowing the properties and values in the triple store.  You need to find out what data indicates years before you can write a query.

Comment: Thank you. See I found the data I need here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/80th_Academy_Awards#Winners_and_nominees I also see this one http://dbpedia.org/page/80th_Academy_Awards. So somehow I need to write union select with Persons namespace? Can I use SPARQL to get information from wikipedia? How to write similar union select?

Comment: The first link is to Wikipedia, which is not the same as DBpedia, though DBpedia's content is based on Wikipedia's.  The second is closer, but where in http://dbpedia.org/page/80th_Academy_Awards do you see a list of people who won in the 80th Academy Awards?  I don't see that data there.

Comment: I guess you have give very useful advice! I found now the data here: http://www.freebase.com/m/02pgky2 I guess it is Linked Open Data and I need now to write a correct SPARQL query to a freebase resource.