# how to query dbpedia.org for resources in "category" pages?

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia

this is a simple query by using sparql in dbpedia.

```
prefix dct:<http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

select   ?x   
where { ?x dct:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Cycle_racing_by_country>
  }
```

or

```
prefix dbc:<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
prefix dct:<http://purl.org/dc/terms/>


select   ?x   
where { ?x dct:subject dbc:Cycle_racing_by_country.
  }
```

it does not return any values.

so how to query 
http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Cycle_racing_by_country
and get its data?

Comment: It's not `/page/` in DBpedia, but `/resource/` in your case. `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Cycle_racing_by_country`

Comment: Also see some notes about dbpedia iris in [How to retrieve XML/RDF data from a dbpedia link or URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279970/how-to-retrieve-xml-rdf-data-from-a-dbpedia-link-or-url)

Comment: @devx the query shouldn't turn anything.  When you visit the resource,  there's aren't any "dct:subject of ..." items.  It doesn't look like this category is the subject of any article, it's just a super-category of a bunch of categories. Can you give an example of what you'd expect your query to return?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor yes you are right, this is good comment and should be as answer, what I want is how to query this resource? to get all URIs in skos:broader then get rdfs:label for each of them?

Comment: Use `dct:subject/skos:broader*` in predicate position.

Comment: You may find questions/ answers like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762696/finding-common-categories-or-supercategories-of-resources helpful,  too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27724741/how-to-build-simple-sparql-query-in-the-right-way is very similar in structure to what it sounds like you want to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As aksw said in a comment, none of the DBpedia entities are identified by IRIS starting with `http://dbpedia.org/page/`, but rather with `http://dbpedia.org/resource/`.

It's easy to make this mistake though, because if you visit, e.g., http://dbpedia.org/resource/Johnny_Cash in the web browser,you get redirected to a URI with /page/ in it. A better solution on DBpedia's part would have been to use content type negotiation to return the html content directly when a browser requests the resource page.

Comment: It is a top category and has no direct instances. You can use `dct:subject/skos:broader*` as predicate.